# Select multiple values (or not) to pascal fields with relational tables mysql (mariadb)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, lazarus

sorry for another question but I'm not good with databases.

I'm developing a small application on Lazarus (Delphi like) and my application is just a couple of SQL statements, inside of my database I have this similar structure for phone storage.

tblUser uid uname udateofbirth uadress

tblPhoneNumber pid uid ptype pnumber

tblPhoneRelation uid pid

What I need to know is if SQL can provide a some kind of list when I'm doing a query with the phones, so I can split this list inside some fields.

With this code from another question, I can retrieve the 'max' number of each type of phone type, but the point is that I can have more than one number of the same kind, like 2 cell phone numbers, or 3 home numbers for example.

```
SELECT u.uname AS Name, u.udateofbirth AS 'Date of B.', 
   MAX(CASE WHEN p.ptype = 1 THEN p.pnumber END) AS 'Cell phone',
   MAX(CASE WHEN p.ptype = 2 THEN p.pnumber END) AS 'Home phone', 
   MAX(CASE WHEN p.ptype = 3 THEN p.pnumber END) AS 'Commercial phone',  
   MAX(CASE WHEN p.ptype = 4 THEN p.pnumber END) AS 'Message phone' 
FROM tblUser AS u 
   JOIN phonerelation ON u.uid = phonerelation.uid 
   JOIN tblPhoneNumber AS p ON p.pid = phonerelation.pid
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Any ideas inside SQL or need to create a for-while code inside of Lazarus retrieving each kind of phone at once? Like: try to find cell phones ... if cell phone count is < 4 try to find home phone... until I get some results.

Ty for the help.

Comment: Please [edit] to include some sample data from each table. It makes it much easier to understand what you're asking. It's also irrelevant that you're not using DB-aware controls (as you've said in a comment to @MartynA below); the use of master-detail queries will be the same regardless how you choose to use the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will give you some ideas:

```
SELECT u.uname AS Name, u.udateofbirth AS 'Date of B.', 
   p1.pnumber AS 'Cell phone',
   p2.pnumber AS 'Home phone', 
   ...
FROM tblUser AS u
   LEFT JOIN (
      select pnumber, uid 
      from phonerelation JOIN 
        tblPhoneNumber AS p ON p.pid = phonerelation.pid WHERE p.ptype = 1) p1
      ON u.uid = p1.uid
   LEFT JOIN (
      select pnumber, uid 
      from phonerelation JOIN 
        tblPhoneNumber AS p ON p.pid = phonerelation.pid WHERE p.ptype = 2) p2
      ON u.uid = p2.uid
   ...
-- Grouping is not needed here
```

Comment: Was a nice try, but before some thinking and research I need something like a array and them get a piece of it, like CPhone.1 or similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a relationship between an "owning" entity (e.g. Person) and arbitrarily many entities of another sort (e.g phone numbers), do **not** try to put the other entities in fields of the owning entity.

Instead, having the owning Entity in one table and the owned ones in a separate table linked to it via the ID of the owning entity.  That way you can have as many of the owned entitities as you need, per Person or whatever.

In Delphi (and Lazarus) you model one-to-many relationships like this as a "Master-Detail" relationship between datasets.  YOu need to read up on this in any of the online tutorials about M-D modeling in Delphi.

Comment: Alread done a link table is the phonerelation with both ids on it, master-detail (for what I'm seen) is used for dbgrid components and I'm not using them, so I need a SQL to do it.

Comment: No, M-Ds are not just for dbgrids, at all.  They are used for modelling precisely the relationship needed to deal with your "but the point is that I can have more than one number of the same kind". Your various "MAX(..." columns in your SQL are exactly the wrong thing to do, if that's your concern.  Anyway, you seem to think you know better, so I'm out.

Comment: dbgrid was a typping error (head is killing me today), but I'm not using Data Contols elements, where I can set a datasource and more, I'm using regular Standart elements like teedits, so that's why I'm using SQL statements in my code, not saying it's wrong or right, just trying to figure out the better way, and thank's for suggestions, I'll take a deeper look later.

Comment: "I'm not using Data Contols" - You should definitely get to grips with Delphi's data-aware controls such as TDBEdit (=data-aware TEdit), TDBMemo, , and TDBGrid.  You're making unnecessary work for yourself by not using them.